# QML: What does the "x" property exactly do and what's the difference with anchors.leftMargin/rightMargin in a ListView?

Tags: qt, qml

I tried to add a margin to a `ListView` element using `anchors.leftMargin` expecting it would create a margin between the screen border and the beginning of the list, but it didn't work at all. Using x instead solved the problem. Here is the code:

```
   ListView {
    id: list
    width: parent.width - sideMargin
    x: sideMargin //works
    anchors.leftMargin: sideMargin //doesn't work
    orientation: ListView.Horizontal
    focus: true
    spacing: 16
    //...
   }
```

So now I am wondering when to use these properties, because reading the docs is not enough for me to understand when to use one or the other.

Comment: I guess you should define `anchors.left` as well to use `anchors.leftMargin`. From the docs: _Note: Anchor margins only apply to anchors; they are not a generic means of applying margins to an Item. If an anchor margin is specified for an edge but the item is not anchored to any item on that edge, the margin is not applied._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Items in QML/QtQuick can be positioned and sized in 3 different ways:

1. Freely using the `x` and `y` properties for position and the `width` and `height` properties for the size.
   See: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#x-prop for more information.

   ```
   ListView {
       id: list
       width: parent.width - sideMargin
       x: sideMargin
       y: topMargin
   }
   ```
2. Using Layouts, or more generally containers, such as `ColumnLayout`. All the work is done by the layout and you don't have to do anything, but you can still provide tips to the container.
3. Using `anchors`. This is done through the `anchors` properties of each `Item`. This works by attaching (anchoring) `Items` against each other.

   ```
   ListView {
       id: list
       anchors.left: parent.left
       anchors.right: parent.right
       anchors.leftMargin: sideMargin
   }
   ```

**Note**: *Do not mix these 3 ways on a single `Item` as you can create conflicts or have unexpected results. In your case you are using method 3 for setting the margin  without setting a position and method 1 for setting the width and thus it does not work.*